Using Tier 1 and Tier 2 Landsat data for the time-series analysis
I'm working with Landsat MSS and Landsat TM, ETM, and OLI data to analyze a NDVI 40-year time series within Google Earth Engine platform. Because of missing Landsat MSS TIER 1 data, I have only LANDSAT MSS TIER 2 data for the 1981-1983 period and the Landsat TM, ETM, and OLI TIER 1 for the 1984-2021 period.  Can I use both TIER 1 and TIER2 products for the same time series? Or do I need any preprocessing of data?

Things are in Tier 2 because they didn't meet the QA requirements to be put in Tier 1, like, for instance, geolocation errors/uncertainties.  You probably need to factor these errors into whatever you're doing.
